# Chrome bookmark manager with notes (and tags?)

Tags: gratis, chrome, bookmark

I've recently started to use bookmarks... a lot. But it's impossible to manage them!

Does a Chrome extension exist that allows me to:

- add notes to bookmarks
- arrange them in folders (the only thing Chrome by default does to help manage them)
- searcheable by note (preferably) and definitely by (multiple) tags
- syncs across any devices I've signed into Chrome with
- easy/quick to use
- add reminders (ie. alert me on a specific day to go back to the page) (?)
- add user definable tags (?)

The ones in question marks are optional, but preferable!

I need it to be free and it to be a Chrome extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **[Evernote Web Clipper](https://evernote.com/webclipper/)**.

> **Evernote Web Clipper** is a simple extension for your web browser that lets you capture full-page articles, images, selected text, important emails, and any web page that inspires you. Save everything to Evernote and keep it forever. (Taken from [this](https://evernote.com/webclipper/guide/))

This extension is available for current modern browser, like Google Chrome. First of all, you must have an [Evernote account](https://evernote.com) in order this extension can be worked. All of your saved clip is your bookmarked page. It will be stored into your Evernote account. So, you can view them via Evernote web or desktop version. I have no experience using another device, like mobile phone. But, I am sure that exists in an application.

Answering what you're looking for:

- add notes to bookmarks

  This is an example what I've done. Bookmarking a page then I add a note to page what I bookmark. You clip your page as the bookmark and add a note to them. I added "I just added a note to this bookmark." text. Look this image below!

[image: Add a note to bookmark]

and the result (via Evernote web)

[image: Result]

- arrange them in folders (the only thing Chrome by default does to help  manage them)

  You can arrange your bookmark via Evernote service. It's outside from your Google Chrome browser. This folder is called as notebook. You must organize the notebook where the page is gonna in before you save them as bookmark. Look this image below!

[image]

- searcheable by note (preferably) and definitely by (multiple) tags

  You can do it. Look this image below!

[image]

- syncs across any devices I've signed into Chrome with

  Like I just said, you can view them via Evernote web or desktop version. I have no experience using another device, like mobile phone. But, I am sure that exists in an application. I have experienced using Evernote desktop, it can sync all of your bookmarked page from your Evernote account.
- easy/quick to use

  I can say it is easy to use. I recommend you to try.
- add reminders (ie. alert me on a specific day to go back to the page) (?)

  You can set the reminder by adding the date and time.

[image]

- add user definable tags (?)

  You can add your own definable tags easily. It has already mention when you are going to bookmark the page. Adding several tags before you bookmark them.

I always use this extension to bookmark the page what inspires me. This extension is free as well as the Evernote service (you can start the free plan). If I missed something, please remind me what is it! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask me if I missed some points on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say the best option would be to have a manually edited page, or set of pages, on or off line, that you store your bookmarks in.  You can add whatever notes you need and it will be cross platform and cross browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this would work for me; I would *like* a tool which is easy-to-use, and quick. Also, I don't need cross browser support, and I'd think any extension would probably use the storage api to sync it across multiple deices you're signed into. I've edited the question. Thanks anyway!